# Tracking training documents

Tags: workflow, training, digital-signature

I need to be able to track 100+ users when they read policies or view training materials. Would the SharePoint Collect Signatures Workflow help us with that? I'm thinking a 3rd party application such as Collaboris DocRead would be better since we have a lot of people to track. But I need to know for sure.